# How to change gray color strip at bottom of repeatbox while "allow pull-up to refesh" is true in smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am working with RepeatBox in smartface. When i am making "Allow pull-up to refresh" to true, i am getting gray color strip at the bottom of the RepeatBox. How to change that color to white.

I tried with Fill color of repeatBox but, didn't help.
Can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a static repeatbox, you can change it's color from palette.

Select "Pull-up Item" from RepeatBox Edit Mode. As you see, I changed its color property as blue.

See the attached picture below : 
[image]

Comment: Thanks merve. Its working fine now. Thanks for the help.